# VS2010 to VS2015 porting errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I get following error when trying to port projects from Visual studio 2010 to vs2015,

1. Error    U1052   file 'ntwin32.mak' not found
2. Warning treat as error no Obj file generated (I can't turn the setting Off for this as it is required project settings)
3. error C2338: The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator is ill-formed.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94469-why-do-i-receive-a-fatal-error-error-u1052-file-ntwin32-mak-not-found-when-i-try-to-simulate-my

Comment: The warnings as errors are generally improvements in the compiler that then enable you to improve your code, you should address each one in turn. The const element issues is most likely a result of improvements in conformance - again you would need to seek an alternative of some sort. You don't provide enough detail to be able to offer more information on what the alternative container(s) could be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167842/4788546